# how to close/stop running application on background android

Tags: android

i want to close or stop running application when i exit from main screen means very first layout of application when i press back button in android.
i use this but my application is running on background

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        }


 **public void onDestroy()
  {
 super.onDestroy();
 System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
 System.exit(0);
    }**
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

get the process ID of your application, and  kill that process onDestroy() method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
 {
    super.onDestroy();

    int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
 }
```

Comment: hi  hotveryspicy whats the means of process id and how can i get it..pls can u explain me in detail thanks...

Comment: whats the use of System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
 System.exit(0); in ondestroy();

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Comment: what is the use of System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
 System.exit(0); in on destroy() and what is difference between onstop() and ondesroy(); in android

Comment: @Jeff yes it is. Can you check for cross voting patterns on the two accounts with the same answer? I suspect some monkey business is going on here.

Comment: Well, only Reno is around here to check the cross voting and give negative reputation's.