# Stop application from running in background?

Tags: android

How to stop application from running in background in android?
I want my application to start fresh everytime it loads. How to do it programatically.

Comment: Please tell me in brief about your question.

Comment: try this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426751/how-to-close-stop-running-application-on-background-android

it may helps you.

Comment: Actually I was doing a cocos2D application and I want to start the game from begning each time. when I call finish() on onStop() the application closes when it starts running. Is that a problem with cocos2D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override `onStop` method of your activity:

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

But I think it's a bad idea to restart your app each time. It's better to override `onStart` method, and handle "restart" here.

Actually, your app doesn't "run" in background. Android OS keeps it in memory, or saves state of your activity to device (and then you can load it, using `savedInstanceState` param in `onCreate` method).

Comment: This will kill the activity when the user suspends the phone, or when otherwise leaving the activity.

Comment: @MarkGjøl, I thought this is what he wants. However it's bad idea )

Comment: That's also what I understood in wht the OP asked. That is an answer to the question, but it's bad practice. The whole Android ecosystem is based on the fact that the user shouldn't have to worry about "terminating" or "starting from scratch" an application.

Comment: It sounds like a badly thought out question (Otherwise it would most likely be longer :)), not taking into account how the phone tends to be used. I would prefer Ocanal's approach by reiniting the application at onResume though. Using this approach the user will simply exit the activity when he hits the power button, not start from scratch.

Comment: @MarkGjøl, I agree with you, but I think the "bad approach" should be in answers too :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) event to reload again, or [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).

**EDIT:**

Actually you need to use these functions to reload your application when user navigate it.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

After adding finish();

This code will completely stop the application.

```
System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
System.exit(0);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole Android ecosystem is based on the fact that the user shouldn't have to worry about "terminating" or "starting from scratch" an application. If you need to start your application from scratch every time, that's probably because you have tasks in your "scratch" that shouldn;t be there, and should probably be somewhere in `onResume`.

Please give us more details if you want a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should make use of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to finish all other activities running in activity pool and call the first activity where you can ask to exit from app