# Close app after some time in background

Tags: java, android, exit

I'm looking for a way to close an android app after some time while the app has not been in focus. For example if the user open up an other app instead, the app should exit after 5 mins. I have tried using runnable and creating a thread. But those method don't seems to work while the app is in the background (maybe they are pause I'm not sure). So how do I close the app when it is not in focus?

For those who are wonder the reason I want to do this is that the app contains some sensitives data about the user so I want to be sure it is all cleared when they aren't using it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "closing" the app?  Android applications don't have the notion of being "closed".  If you want to destroy your activities, you can do so using the activity lifecycle.  If you want to stop your services, then you need to "notify" your services when the app goes into foreground - and the services can take care of stopping themselves after 5 minutes, most likely, using AlarmManager.

Comment: By close i mean the application is no longer running and all the memory it allocated was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

A field inside activity class:

```
private Thread t = null;
```

Inside `onResume()`:

```
if(t!=null) {
    if(t.isAlive()) {
        t.interrupt();
        t.join();
    }
    t=null;
}
```

Inside `onPause()`:

```
t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5*60*1000);
                // Wipe your valuable data here
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the process ID of your application, and kill that process onDestroy() method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
   super.onDestroy();

   int id= android.os.Process.myPid();

   android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
}
```

Refer- [how to close/stop running application on background android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426751/how-to-close-stop-running-application-on-background-android)

Edit- Use this with AlarmManager

Comment: This does not give me some sort of timer. Also it waits until android feels it needs the memory with might be never if the device got lots of memory.

Comment: This was an addition to one of the comment. Use it with AlarmManager.

Comment: This is a hard-close of the app. IMO this wouldn't be an appropriate way to get the OP's requirement done. There might be a service or broadcast receiver running during executing this code and then it might leads to your app to misbehave, since all app's components will run on a single process and killing this process would result in halting of whole app.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend calling `finish()` in the `onPause()` or `onStop()` callbacks. A `TimerTask` will not survive `onPause()` and a Service does not appear, on face value, to give you options. Maybe you can start a service, sleep the thread the service runs on, then kill the processes your app has after the sleep timer expires.

Alternatively, you can just implement some security libraries to help secure the data from other apps.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is the Google Services link.

Comment: A possibility is to set up an alarm using AlarmManager in `onStop()` to fire after 5 min, and cancels the alarm in `onRestart()`.  Then finish the process under `onReceive()` of the BroadcastReceiver for the alarm.

Comment: As far as I know, `Timer` is a legacy Java class that is completely unaware of the Android framework.  It will survive `onPause()` unless you cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem with what you're trying to do is that your `Activity` may not exist in memory at all when it's "running" in the background.  The Android framework may have destroyed the activity instance and even the process it was running in.  All that exists may be the persistent state you saved in `onSaveInstanceState(...)` and a screenshot for the recent apps list.  There may be nothing for you to get a reference to and kill.

[Frank Brenyah's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543687/1953590) to call `finish()` in `onPause()` will prevent your activity from running in the background at all, but this is the closest you can get to what you want.  You probably only want to do this when `isChangingConfigurations()` is false.  But even when all your app's activities are finished, Android may keep the process and `Application` instance around to avoid recreating them later.  So you may also want to use [Bhush_techidiot's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543470/1953590) of killing the process.  Do this in `onPause()` because the activity may be destroyed without a call to `onDestroy()`.